# How to write this Makefile?

Tags: makefile, linux-device-driver

I'm new to programming and I need to make the following Makefile and can't find a website to explain to me.

[image]

A bit of explaining:

F.c - Kernel module and it uses declared function in A.h, B.h, C.h.

Each X.h functions are implemented in X.c (as always).

Can somebody please help me?
Before I had only 2 files, A.h and F.c and my Makefile was:

```make
obj-m + = f.o
    
all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

And it worked out, but I don't understand the idea behind the code.

Comment: `obj-m += foo.o  foo-y := A.c B.c C.c D.c F.c` (these are **two** lines) Note, there should **not** be _foo.c_, it's _virtual_ name for the resulting module.

Answer (score 0):

Even though B.h and C.h may include A.h and D.h, they do not depend on it to exist.  So something like:

```
B.h: A.h D.h
```

is incorrect.  B.h already exists, it does not change when A.h is changed.

But the object modules do depend on the inclusions and must be rebuilt when any of the dependent include files or source files change.

```
F.o: A.h B.h C.h D.h F.c

B.o: A.h B.h C.h D.h B.c

C.o: A.h B.h C.h D.h C.c

D.o: D.h D.c
```

See also: makedepend

Hope this helps. If it is not enough, ask some questions in the comments and someone will edit in the answers.

Comment: I still don't understand how to compile a module kernel. F is a module kernel and the rest are implementation of functions, so they can be compiled using gcc. But how do I make a makefile that compile F.o in one way, and the rest in another way?

I need to add that I do not fully understand why does compiling kernel module and regular files need to be different. I just came to this conclusion because the Makefile I was given in the exercise (and showed in the question) is not my usual Makefile using gcc.

Comment: @Itsme  I don't know how to compile and link for the kernel.  Posting another question targeted towards that specific issue would probably be a good idea.